# How to approach a machine learning problem?

Tags: machine-learning, python, predictive-modeling, supervised-learning

I'm a beginner in machine learning, and no real statistical background ( just basic knowledge ). I comprehend half of what is said on forums about statistical methods and techniques for normalizing data and putting up plots to see data distribution. Anyway, i managed to create multiple predictive models following steps from people on **Kaggle**. However, i would like to receive some knowledge on the steps that must be taken while building a model. I'll use an example i worked on to demonstrate my steps, and if you spot a *beginner's mistake* and you will, just point.

I started by viewing my data ( combine is the test set + trainset minus the target column to predict )

```
print(combine.isnull().sum())
```

1. age                   0
2. cmp               42855
3. code_dept           654
4. id_opportunite        0
5. mca                4539
6. nb_enfants         1624
7. nom_organisme         0
8. situation            58

Okay , some potential predictors have a variety of values of 'nulls'!

NOTE :

**Situation** : type = string , indicating the social situation of the person.

**Nb_Enfants** : type = int , indicating number of children.

**cmp** : type = string, indicating the name of the company this person was contracted with ( which is not a common information to get from a person over a phone call, which explains the huge number of nulls on that column )

**nom_organisme** : type=string , name of the call center that referred this person to us ( might be a good predictor , some centers send statiscally people more likely to sign than other centers according to my plot )

**Age** : type=int, no explanation needed i suppose

**code_dept** : type=int, refers to id's of departments , a department is a slice of a big town so these are id's to locations. ( it shoud be logically a good predictor since chance of signature is higher in some departments than others )

**Question 1:** is there a conclusion to draw from this ? or a predictor to eliminate like **'cmp'** ? or a must-do like replace the nulls or predict them?

These are most of the features i'll be using. i want to predict if a person will sign or not with the company. I ommited the ***sign column***, but it's a **binary** value

This is my output distribution. just below

> Signature: 11674 (17.7 percent), Non Signature: 54250 (82.3 percent), Total: 65924

*So i have 2 output classes 0 and 1 and they are imbalanced 17% to 82%!

**Question 2:**  should i use **SMOTE** in this case? or not? and are there other conclusions to draw from this?*

I started by removing what you guys call **Outliers** that of course i made sure they were random noises and mistakes in the data capture. ( Yes i made sure it was noise rather than a pattern that needed to be taught to the model )

Then, i visualized the columns one by one and noted the behavior against the sign column. These are some examples :

[image: nb_enfants]

This shows the percentage of people who signed in **Yellow** and those who have not in **Blue** per number of children ( from 0 to 5 ).

Also i figured a value_counts was necessary!

```
df3.nb_enfants.value_counts()
```

[image: nb_enfants!]

**Question 3 :** Are there other conclusions to draw from this plot? or other ways of extracting information from the possible feature? and can I decide just by looking at this plot wether **nb_enfants** is a good predictor or not?

then i went on and **'manually'** picked features i liked ( That's how i roll ).

Just kidding, i picked features that would logically have an impact on the prediction ( I know there are ways to spot features unseen to the naked eye, but i think i'm not on that statistical level of displaying data and extracting informations from, any advice on how to do that is welcome )

**Question 4** : What's a better indicator to a good predictor in my case?

I also **manually** encoded **age** into **7** classes, **situation** ( which contains strings, needed encoding anyway ) into **6** classes, created **2** features based on **code_dept** ( where the person lives ) and **nom_organisme** ( which company referred this person to our company ) *where i assign a class to each **code_dept** or **nom_organisme** based on the percentage of people who signed.*

I didn't like the dummy variables since, i'm deploying this machine later on a server, to be used as a webservice, and i need to *encode* the "people" that get sent over requests the same way i encoded my train dataset, and the only way i managed to do that is by static encoding via **IF's** in a function that i apply to the "person" that gets through.

**Question5 :** I know static is bad for maintenance or updating in general. Is there way to do that webservice transformation without using static encoding? Also is it recommended at all to use static encoding on every feature?

[image: This is a sample of a train row]

**Question6 :** Any remarks on the data ?

I set up a correlation matrix for some features by doing this :

```
plt.figure(figsize=(16,14)) 
foo=sns.heatmap(train.drop(['id_opportunite','mca','code_dept','nom_organisme'],axis=1).corr(), vmax=0.6,square=True, annot=True)
```

[image: Correlation Matrix]

**Question7 :** What conclusions one should draw from this matrix?

I went with :
 `X = train[['age','classe_dep','situation','nb_enfants','classe_organisme']]
y = train.loc[:,'signer']`

Result on decision tree :

```
le score maximale de l'algorithme Decision Tree est :  84.11%  pour max_leaf_nodes =  52
```

Result on the test set : **75%** accuracy.

**Question8 :** Any general thoughts or remarks? Thanks!

Answer should be verification of my steps, and some remarks on one or many of my questions! Thanks!

Comment: I'm not a big fun of clustering numerical variables such as the age in group, i prefer to let the tree decide which are the best splits. For the rest you didn't provide much details but I don't see anything clearly wrong. Why you created the correlation matrix?

Comment: To see how the potential predictors are interacting with each other , and with the prediction column. What other details would you rather see? i can always edit my question for clarity. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Blenzus, and welcome!
This question is way too broad. If you could split it up into a more specific, detailed question, you're much more likely to get a useful answer. Asking "what am I doing wrong?" with your entire project, is unlikely to get a response.
To add to this: if you break your problem down into smaller specific questions, I'm sure you'll find the answers to those questions already on this site. Good luck :)

Comment: Thanks for the input , I will!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plenty of questions there. I will answer about the accuracy one:

75% is larger than random chance and might have use. But you need to consider what is relevant for your application.

For example, suppose you are dealing with a security issue. Denying access to someone that is entitled to it is less damaging than allowing access to someone who is not.

If you want to reduce the number of phone calls to sell a product you want a model that will tell you to call the maximum of potential clients and even a shrinking of 10% of useless call is a good model with good profit if you don't make it absurdly expensive to keep operating.